# Windows 7 : How to set default choice as "Yes" in UAC?

Tags: windows-7, uac

Is there any way to set default choice as "Yes" ,while running any application in windows 7 it will prompt us to allow or not . By default select option is "no" always .

I want to set "Yes" as a default option. So that i can access fast through keyboard by hitting enter key .
Thanks for your reply.

Sample captures of UAC prompt message

[image: Sample screen capture]
[image]

Comment: Default of "NO" is especially annoying when configured to require a password.  Did they really think I bothered to type my password in order to refuse launch?!?

Comment: You took the words out of my mouth, @BenVoigt. Asinine.

Comment: @Marquee: I've since discovered that as long as password entry is the default authentication mechanism, it works correctly ("Yes" is default).  But most installs have some form of smart card driver installed (even if no hardware is present), and this not only steals focus from the password entry (which is annoying, but at least your hand is probably already on the mouse to move focus), but also changes the default button to "No", which is just a UI disaster as already mentioned.

Comment: @BenVoigt - thanks for the response. I'll try this out when I get home. You should add this as an answer, as it is (obviously) still relevant.

Comment: @Marquee: See http://superuser.com/q/642991/29943 (which answer you should upvote).

Answer (score 4):

This might offer some kind of workaround:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html

Comment: +1 Interesting workaround. But to answer the Op's question (I will post here as you provide a solution), no you can not change the default behavior, you must use a workaround.