# Make UAC prompt in remote desktop not default to smart card

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop, uac

In a remote desktop session, both client and server are Windows 8 Pro (w/Media Center), UAC prompts appear as follows (username and Microsoft account e-mail intentionally obscured, it does appear correctly on the actual screen):

[image]

Now, neither client nor server has a smart card reader, so I use a password to approve elevation (and yes, I want to require password entry, not click-through).  Notice that the smart card options appear above the password option and the preselected option is for a smart card, even though every time I've approved elevation I've done so with a password.

Can I either

1. Get rid of the smart card options, or
2. Make the dialog appear with the password option selected/focused and ready for password entry?

---

EDIT: "Smart cards" is not checked under "Local resources"

[image]

Comment: If you edit your RDP connectoid for that computer, and uncheck "Smart Cards" under Local Resources, does it still do it?

Comment: @techie007: See added screenshot, is that what you're referring to?  It already was unchecked.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was talking about. :) Are you logged into the local computer with a domain account?

Comment: No, on the client I'm logged in with a local account (upgraded from Win7), and the server I'm logged in with a Microsoft account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable `Smartcard Credential Provider`.

The easiest way is to use [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) tool from Sysinternals. In `Winlogon` tab disable mentioned provider (you may need to uncheck *Hide Windows Entries* in Options menu).

[image]

Alternatively you may just remove following registry key:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers\{8FD7E19C-3BF7-489B-A72C-846AB3678C96}`

This worked for me on Windows 10, but it should work on Windows 8 too.

Comment: Thanks very much, this works perfectly and it also solves the major annoyance with the default button after typing a password being "No".  Why would I go to the trouble of typing my password if I didn't intend to approve the action?  Well, now that password entry is the default focus, the default button is also corrected.  Thank you thank you thank you!